# ARM7 TDMI undefined instruction exception manual generation

Tags: exception, arm, opcode

I am trying to test out some exception handling code running on an ARM7 TDMI processor.  I am wanting to manually create an instruction opcode which will generate the "Undefined instruction" exception.  So far, I've done this:

```
void createUndefinedException()
{    
    static const int instr = 0x26889912; // bad opcode
    ((void(*)(void))instr)();
}
```

I arrived at the above opcode because of a [reference page](http://www.wss.co.uk/pinknoise/ARMinstrs/ARMinstrs.html) I found today on the web that talks about undefined instruction opcodes at the very bottom.

The above code generates the prefetch abort exception instead of the undefined instruction exception.

Anyone have an idea of how to create this easily?

I just want to verify my handling of this exception is going to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

create an asm file

```
.globl test_function
test_function:
.word 0x26889912
bx lr
```

assemble it

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as fun.s -o fun.o
```

call it from your C code

```
extern void test_function ( void );

...

test_function();
```

then add it to the list of objects you are linking

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc myprogram.c fun.o -o myprogram
```

and run it.

Comment: Even though this value was causing prefetch aborts when I tried to branch to it, it does not cause a undefined instruction exception when trying to execute it as an opcode.  So, I'm back to looking for a truly undefined opcode on the ARM7.  I have the mechanism in place, if I can just find the right opcode.

Comment: from the ARM ARM:  architecturally undefined:  cond01111111xxxxxxxxxxxx1111xxxx so try something like 0xE7FFFFFF

Comment: another one is undefined instruction:  cond00110x00xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx so 0xE30FFFFF

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function out of the address of the int:

```
typedef void (*Exception)(void)
static unsigned long illegalOpcode=0x26889912;
Exception e=(Exception)&illegalOpcode;
e();
```